# How to declare a constant from a variable?

Tags: go, variables, constants

**What is the problem:**

I would like to declare a constant from a variable. Here is a very simple version of what I'd like to do:

[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/T0hsIhyt0tn)

```
someVar := 1
const someConst = someVar // error: const initializer someVar is not a constant
fmt.Printf("%d %d", someVar, someConst)
```

How can I make `someConst` a constant? Is this impossible in go?

**Why do I want this?**

`someVar` is a global Variable. It is fine that this can change. `someConst` is function scoped. For the scope of this function it should not change.

In DB terms: `someConst` is an immutable snapshot of `someVar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Go's [constants](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants) must be compile-time constants.

> A [constant declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_declarations) binds a list of identifiers (the names of the constants) to the values of a list of [constant expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).

And

> Constant expressions may contain only constant operands and are evaluated at compile time.

`someVar` in your example is a variable, it does not qualify for the "constant operands".

If the package level variable may change during the execution of your function which change you don't want to observe, make a local copy of the variable, and use the local copy.

Also note that if the variable's value may change due to a (concurrent) goroutine, access to it (when making the copy) must be synchronized (just like the write to it in other goroutines).

For example:

```
var (
    someVarMu sync.RWMutex
    someVar   = 1
)

func foo() {
    someVarMu.RLock()
    myVar := someVar
    someVarMu.RUnlock()

    // Use myVar
    fmt.Println(myVar)
}
```